# CSS: Overflow:scroll; not appearing

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

EDIT: Answer here:[Google Chrome Bug - Overflow:auto | scroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462395/google-chrome-bug-overflowauto-scroll-doesnt-work/23462583?noredirect=1#comment35970896_23462583)

My overflow scroll bar is not appearing in my results page.php. I've checked for errors such as not including a height along with the class, but I'm getting nowhere. Maybe it's the php which is messing it up?

[image]

You can see the problem yourself by going here http://biketurtle.co/search.php
and searching for bikes in 'Antrim' for under 1000 euro

Here's the CSS class:

```
.textarea

{
height: 848px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
list-style: none;
overflow:scroll;
position:relative;

}
```

And here is some of the HTML:

```
<section class="section">

<div class="textarea">
<h1>Search</h1>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
include("db_connect.php"); 

$sql = "SELECT brand,model,type,town,location,university,price,cond,description FROM       placead WHERE price < ? AND location = ?";
if($stmt = $link->prepare($sql))
{
$stmt->bind_param('is', $_POST['price'], $_POST['location']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt- >bind_result($brand,$model,$type,$town,$location,$university,$price,$condition,$description    );


/* store result */
$stmt->store_result(); //required to get num_rows   
echo"==============================================================";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
printf("Your search returned : %d records <br/>", $stmt->num_rows);
echo "<br/>";
echo"==============================================================";

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo "<br />Price.................................".$price." Euro.";
echo "<br />location..............................".$location;
echo "<br />Brand.................................".$brand;
echo "<br />Model.................................".$model;
echo "<br />Type..................................".$type;
echo "<br />Town..................................".$town;
echo "<br />University............................".$university;
echo "<br />Condition.............................".$condition;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br />                Description           ";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>".$description;
echo "<br/>";
echo"==============================================================";
}   
//close the crecordset
$stmt->close();
}
$link->close();
}
else {
?>
// contd......
```

Comment: Show the rendered html, not the php code.

Comment: The rendered html is very messy in 'view source'. The page is here: http://biketurtle.co/search.php Just search with location = 'Antrim' and price < 1000

Comment: "<option value="Roscommon">Roscommon/option>" - you don't have a close bracket on this line

Comment: Thanks po4teda! Original problem persists though.

Comment: Full code  here: http://jsfiddle.net/53qs5/  Handy site.

Comment: Try overflow: auto; ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors. I created a jsfiddle with a textbox with the same CSS properties here: http://jsfiddle.net/TD6HX/

```
#limit_height
{
    width: 200px;
    height:300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
}
```