# Google Chrome Bug - Overflow:auto | scroll doesn't work

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow

Here's my site in Chrome with he text running outside the box:

[image]

And here it is in .IE with no problem

[image]

Here's the relevant CSS

```
.section
{
height: 1000px;
width: 670px;
border: thick solid rgb(51,97,120);
border-radius: 15px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(Images/diag_pattern.png);
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
overflow:auto;
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipses;
}
```

Very annoying? Is there anything I can do. An alternative way to show my results?

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo showing the problem.

Comment: It should be "text-overflow: ellipsis;" and yes, a fiddle would make debugging a lot easier ;)

Comment: Please post all of your relevent HTML and CSS within a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/53qs5/ The relevent CSS is already posted. The actual page is www.biketurtle.co/search. Justsearch for bikes in 'Antrim' under 1000 and you'll get the same as the screenshot.

Comment: Your site requires a username and password for us to view it. Are you able to provide us with these credentials?

Comment: It's viewable now at www.biketurtle.co/search.php Sorry about that

Comment: `http://www.biketurtle.co/search` is giving a 404 not found error.

Comment: Managed to find it at `http://www.biketurtle.co/search.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit both your `section` and `textarea` classes:

```
.section {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 670px;
    border: thick solid rgb(51, 97, 120);
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(Images/diag_pattern.png);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow-y: hidden;      /* ---- Make this hidden */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.textarea {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 650;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;      /* ---- Then make this scrollable */
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to have an affect oddly. Still works in .IE and not in Chrome.

Comment: @COOLBEANS - I have made an edit to my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tip my hat to you sir :-) What was happening exactly?

Comment: Fantastic :) Basically, you were trying to make your `section` class scroll, although, it did not contain any content. The class with the content was `textarea`, therefore, it had to have the style of `scroll`. Hence, we needed to hide the overflow for the parent, and make the child scroll inside of it :)

Comment: I wonder how .IE was able to make it work in that case? It shouldn't have really,should it?

Comment: I think that maybe IE was looking inside of its child to view its contents as well. Although, I am not entirely sure.