# CSS: Chrome Ignoring media Query: works fine in IE? Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, media-queries

My website is here: http://biketurtle.co/Home.php

Here are the two CSS media queries:

```
@media all and (min-width: 800px){...}
```

and

```
@media all and (max-width: 799px){...}
```

The full CSS is here if it's helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/vj66T/

When I go to my .IE browser the page changes as I hoped it would. But, chrome just stays the same. I had a similar problem yesterday day where Chrome ignored overflow:auto and it worked in .IE that time also. I doubt these problems are related, but here was the solution yesterdays problem if it helps any bit: [Google Chrome Bug - Overflow:auto | scroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462395/google-chrome-bug-overflowauto-scroll-doesnt-work/23462583?noredirect=1#comment35970896_23462583)

Here is a picture of how it SHOULD look! on Chrome, but doesn't for smaller screens:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the site in Google Chrome and it works just fine, the media queries are working fine and the layout is changing depending on the window width.

SOLUTION: The solution was to clear browser cache.

UPDATE: I see the same in Google Chrome

[image: Screenshot of your page from Google Chrome]

Comment: This should be a comment...

Comment: you should not downvote, just comment it and I can edit.

Comment: As an answer, it's not applicable. If you edit it to become a legitimate answer I will remove my downvote. Otherwise, you should create a comment and remove this as an answer...

Comment: Are you sure? The nave bar on the side should become horizontal and everything should go right up against the left hand side on smaller screens? I can't see why my Chrome would be different to yours? hmm I'll include a picture.

Comment: @COOLBEANS see the update, It looks ok when I access the website from Google Chrome

Comment: SOLUTION! I had to clear my cache in Chrome. It must have been storing the images and when I was updating the server it was just looking at my cache. I wouldn't have tried it without your help. Thanks

Comment: I just updated the solution for people to know common issues they may face while coding

Comment: As promised, I've removed my down vote. Thank you for updating your answer to provide more details and better clarification.